# Rails for Zombies Level 2 Challenge 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-for-zombies

I'm not sure how to solve this. I tried rewatching the videos but it doesn't say how to link "presence" and "uniqueness" validations to zombie's name.
Any suggestions?

Picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nAEs.png

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as

```
validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

Answer (score 0):

it is giving this error on typing above code
ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation